# Is there a more convenient VPN toggle in iOS 9.1?

Tags: iphone, ios, vpn

Is there an convenient way for me to toggle VPN on or off in iOS 9.1 without navigating through the Settings screen each time?

Previously (on Android), I used an app to automate this based on my location and it was pretty reliable. Searching through the App Store, I am unable to find any advanced automation apps.

I have discovered FlipControlCenter which would place a convenient toggle button in the swipe up menu, however I'm currently running iOS 9.1 and would like to avoid jailbreaking if possible.

I am aware that some paid VPN services do have apps which can be launched and used to toggle VPN on or off, however I am running my own personal VPN service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [VPNOn](https://github.com/lexrus/VPNOn) ([AppStore link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vpn-on/id951344279)). It has convenient toggles in Notification Center and Apple Watch.

Answer (score 0):

use [Launcher](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/launcher-notification-center/id905099592?mt=8) to add a link to Settings->VPN and many more to your Notification Center

Comment: For the sake of being up-to-date, Settings-based links are [not available any more starting with iOS 11](https://www.cromulentlabs.com/launcher/help/).